# Two functions such that $f$ is continuous at $0$, $g$ is discontinuous at $0$, but $f+g$ is continuous at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Can anyone give an example and justify the answer. I am not sure how to prove such a thing.

[image]

Comment: Hint $g = (f + g) - f$.

Comment: @peterag Thanks for that, really useful. Would this be sufficient for the 'justify your answer' part?

Comment: @Milos Yes if you phrase it correctly. The difference of two continuous function is continuous. If we assume that $f+g$ is continuous, we will proof that $g$ is continuous, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Milos Feel free to add your own answer and accept it if you have no further questions.